Can I use Advanced Installer in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline?
I am working on a project where I need to create a Windows application installer using Advanced Installer. I want to integrate this process into my GitLab CI/CD pipeline to automate the creation of MSI/EXE packages during the build process.
